# Android: add divider to top of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I was able to add dividers on the bottoms of cells in a `RecyclerView`:

```
this.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(this.recyclerView.context, layoutManager.orientation)
this.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

How can I add a line to the top of the very first cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't make same divider between Header and items/Footer and items. User will get confused if it could be selected or not. For a good User Interface, I recommended to make colour background on header/footer. Like this one :

[image]

If you insist on adding the divider in header, you could edit it on your ItemDecoration just like the item divider. Use this divider for your Header Item Decoration. More detail visit [DividerItemDecoration](https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e)

```
fun drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
        val left = parent.getPaddingLeft()
        val right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight()

        val childCount = parent.getChildCount()
        val child : View = parent.getChildAt(i)
        val params : RecyclerView.LayoutParams = child.getLayoutParams();
        val top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        val bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
```